# Convergence of a double sum of reciprocals of lowest common multiples

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, least-common-multiple

Let $m,n$ be positive integers and let ${\rm lcm}(m,n)$ denote the *lowest common multiple* of $m$ and $n$. Now consider the double sum

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{\rm lcm}(m,n)}.
$$

Is there a way to bound this sum from above or prove something about its convergence? If so, how can I go about this?

---

Comment: Related: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.2508.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{\rm lcm}(m,n)}\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=n}^{n} \frac{1}{{\rm lcm}(n,m)}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly,
$$
(m,n)\le mn
$$
and hence
$$
\frac{1}{mn}\le \frac{1}{(m,n)}
$$
But
$$
\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{mn}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}=\infty.
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(m,n)}=\infty
$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{{\rm lcm}(m,n)}\ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{\text{lcm}(1,n)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$$ which is divergent.